# Flex PNG/JPG decoder

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, air

Now, I run the following code in Flash to get the raw binary data of one PNG file.

var fr:FileReference = new FileReference;
fr.browse();
fr.load(...);

After loading complete, I think I can access the PNG file binary data from fr.data, now, I want to display this PNG picture in my application, could you please tell me, is there anything like that can decode the PNG format binary data into a Bitmap?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display it you should be able to use [Loader.loadBytes()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Loader.html#loadBytes%28%29).

Loader is a DisplayObject, so you can add it to the display list and it will show the image.